# Weird instruction identified on disassembler produced assembly code

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, disassembly, objdump

Test is on x86 32bit Linux, Ubuntu 12.04, GCC 4.6.3 objdump 2.22

Basically when I use gcc to produce assembly code of function **foo** like this:

```
gcc -S foo.c -O2
as --listing-lhs-width=4 -alcdn foo.s
```

At the end of function **foo**, I can get a sequence of instructions like this (I modified it and attached each instruction with its machine code to make it clear):

```
             ......
1977                                                 .cfi_restore_state
1978  8B150000 0000                                  movl    nodes, %edx
1979  89442410                                       movl    %eax, 16(%esp)
1980  A1000000 00                                    movl    i_depth, %eax
1981  8974240C                                       movl    %esi, 12(%esp)
1982  C7442404 FC000000                              movl    $.LC55, 4(%esp)
1983  89542414                                       movl    %edx, 20(%esp)
1984  89442408                                       movl    %eax, 8(%esp)
1985  C7042401 000000                                movl    $1, (%esp)
1986  E8FCFFFF FF                                    call    __printf_chk
1987  E937FFFF FF                                    jmp     .L181
1988                                         .L186:
1989  E8FCFFFF FF                                    call    __stack_chk_fail

foo1:
```

which looks normal.

However, when I compiled + linked to create the ELF executable file, and then disassemble it with `objdump` like this:

```
gcc foo.c -O2
objdump -Dr -j .text foo
```

The instruction produced by disassembler looks like this (I modified a little bit to make it easier to understand):

```
11856 89442410                                mov %eax,0x10(%esp)
11857 A1000000 00                             mov 0x80851AC,%eax
11858 8974240C                                mov %esi,0xC(%esp)
11859 C7442404 00000000                       movl $S_0x8064658,0x4(%esp)
11860 89542414                                mov %edx,0x14(%esp)
11861 89442408                                mov %eax,0x8(%esp)
11862 C7042401 000000                         movl $0x1,(%esp)
11863 E8FCFFFF FF                             call __printf_chk
11864 E933FFFF FF                             jmp 0x80547EB
11865
11866 E8FCFFFF FF                             S_0x80548BC : call __stack_chk_fail
11867 EB0D                                    jmp foo1
11868 90                                      nop
11869 90                                      nop
11870 90                                      nop
11871 90                                      nop
11872 90                                      nop
11873 90                                      nop
11874 90                                      nop
11875 90                                      nop
11876 90                                      nop
11877 90                                      nop
11878 90                                      nop
11879 90                                      nop
11880 90                                      nop
11881                                         foo1:
```

Looking at the end of function foo, I find out a sequence of instructions which can not be found in the original assembly code.

It seems like a padding issue, but I am not sure.

So my questions are:

1. What are these instruction sequences for?
2. Is there anyway to tell the assembler (or linker?) 'do not generate these instruction sequences'? Because basically I am working an assembly code analysis tool, and these instruction sequences are very annoying for the coding.

Comment: That is magic for detecting stack corruption - basically some guard buffer is placed an initialized on the stack and then before the function returns that buffer is checked for being unaltered.

Comment: @sharptooth, I don't get it.. Could you please provide any detailed material about this..? Thx!

Comment: Here's Visual C++ equivalent http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290051%28v=vs.71%29.aspx to get you started. Btw note you have only 25 views so far - this is because you didn't include `c` tag.

Comment: @sharptooth, Modified! Thank you and I will take a look!

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, the only difference I see are the bunch of `NOP` instructions. And that's padding for alignment (although you might have pasted the address wrong, `foo1` should be aligned). Edit: for alignment, see the `gcc` manual about the `-falign-*` options.

Comment: Yep the addresses are wrong. 1867 contains a two-byte instruction, the next should be 1869 not 1868. There's one extra `nop` by the looks.

Comment: @Jester, No, `11867 EB0D                                    jmp foo1` is the critical difference.

Comment: @davmac, I am afraid this is not addr. It should be just the line number.

Comment: @Jester, please double check the code attached. It is interrelate about `E9` vs. `EB`.

Comment: Oh, okay. That's still just padding. Have you tried the `-falign-*` options?

Comment: @sharptooth This is code section, stack is not stored in object files.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: Sure, but this code is for stack cookies manipulation.

Comment: Don't forget, if your assembler analysis tool is going to have to work on real world assembly code, you'll have to deal with whatever the compilers generate under any sets of options whatsoever.